# How to manage workers in google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I ran the program [datastorewordcount.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/DatastoreWordCount.java) from Google cloud cookbook examples.  When I observe dataflow monitoring console, the workers never exceed one.  I am using Google cloud 1 year free usage.

Why is autoscaling never increasing number of workers?

Comment: If this is the [example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/cookbook#datastorewordcount) you ran, can you provide your command line options and pom.xml file so we can know how you run the job? You may want to check the log for your job in the Stackdriver logging in Google Cloud Platform Console to see if there are warnings or errors you can supply. Also, in the Quota page if you see Compute Engine API depleted its In-use IP addresses, then that would affect autoscaling as well.

Comment: What were these three options you specified when you run the job, autoscalingAlgorithm, numWorkers and maxNumWorkers? The workers should scale up when these options were properly set. Check this documentation for the explanation of the options https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options. 1 year free usage will not limit the workers you can use.

Answer (score 0):

It usually takes my pipelines a few minutes before it starts upping the number of workers.

You can specify the initial number of workers with `numWorkers` in your 'pipeline options'

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options

Comment: Thanks Alex. In the dataflow monitor console, only one cpu is listed in the resources section.  Is this because I am using free 1 year usage plan.